# How to get a JSON object that is parseable by TypedJSOn and class-transformer

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I have tried using both class-transformer and TypedJson and both only work with using an object declared in this form:

```
      let productJson = {
                           name: 'Aerosol',
                           productId: 'QSRT001',
                           description: 'A great product, air purifier'
                        }
```

However, I need to read the file of products from the file system. Both libraries are unable to work with the JSON because it is escaped with \\ for the quoted strings.  Is there a way to unescaped the JSON read from the file so it can be represented in the productJson above? Please, please help!! It's hard to capture the output as it is very large. I removed most of the content, this is a small sample.

```
"{ \"name\"   : \"John Smith\",\n" +
      "  \"sku\"    : \"20223\",\n" +
      "  \"price\"  : 23.95,\n" +
      "  \"shipTo\" : { \"name\" : \"Jane Smith\",\n" +
      "               \"address\" : \"123 Maple Street\",\n" +
      "               \"city\" : \"Pretendville\",\n" +
      "               \"state\" : \"NY\",\n" +
      "               \"zip\"   : \"12345\" },\n" +
      "  \"billTo\" : { \"name\" : \"John Smith\",\n" +
      "               \"address\" : \"123 Maple Street\",\n" +
      "               \"city\" : \"Pretendville\",\n" +
      "               \"state\" : \"NY\",\n" +
      "               \"zip\"   : \"12345\" }\n" +
      "}\n" +
      "\n";
```

I have been able to get a better representation. I need to be able to let the object get the TypedJSON to be able to process the file. if the file has the \ it is not processed by the TypedJSON correctly.

Is it possible to get it in the form like in productJson?

Comment: Could you post an example JSON from the file system?

Comment: Yes, let me do that quickly

Comment: Still unclear. Does the file start with a `"` amd not end with a `"`? Are the `\n` actual newlines, or backslash + `n`?